# Cannot map LAlt + any key in autohotkey

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

This should be very simple but I cannot make it work...
This script will switch to the next desktop when the left alt key is pressed:

```
LAlt::^#Right ;Next Desktop
return
```

I want to have this except I want to press left alt + '&' instead.
But apparently addind any key after the alt make it stop working.
For example

```
LAlt & w::^#Right ;Next Desktop
return
```

should work with left key + w but it doesn't do anything.
I know that '!' can be alt, but using '!w' will also not work in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this:

```
  LAlt & w:: Send ^#{Right} ;Next Desktop
```